# Java alternative for 'sort -V'

Tags: java, shell, sorting, comparator

I'm looking for a pure-java alternative for the shell command: `sort -V`. I'm looking for a Comparator class that can simply be plugged in.
The `sort -V` command simply sorts files with a version system (i.e. `3.2.0-11` is 10 bigger than `3.2.0-1`, not .1 bigger).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry if you think I mention obvious -- just define such comparator by yourself and you good to go.

Comment: Yes, but how would I do that? I'm just a newbie at Java :)

Comment: @lkjoel http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: the way I would do it is have the sort 'key' be the string, split by non-digits, and converting the digits into integers

Comment: Start with defining order on versions. Man page for `sort` just mentions that `sort -V` is `natural sort of (version) numbers within text`. Honestly, I don't know what it means. Your best bet is to look up C source of `sort` and then implement `Comparator` in Java accordingly.

Comment: ok thanks. How would I remove non-digits?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a generic "like a human" comparator once. I've got no code to show but the idea was to split each string like this:

```
fragments = empty string collection
buffer = first character of the string
if character is digit, mode = NUMBER, else mode = TEXT
while there are characters left
   c = next character
   if c is digit and mode is NUMBER, add character to buffer
   else if c is not a digit and mode is TEXT, add character to buffer
   else
     add contents of buffer (as string) to the fragments collection,
     flip mode from TEXT to NUMBER or vice versa
     buffer = c
   end if
end while
add remaining contents of buffer to fragments
```

So now you've got a list of substrings, containing alternating number fragments and non-number fragments. (E.g. `something-1.0.26.jar` will become `{ 'something-', '1', '.', '0', '.', '26', '.jar' }`)

If you do this to both strings, you can then write a comparator that compares the pairs fragments one by one: if both are numbers, do a numerical comparison, if both are texts, string compare, if one is number, the other is text, number comes first.

I know this is a lot more than what you want but it is quite a useful piece of code to have in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

Beginner:

If your version string is clearly defined then you can split it up into different numbers and compare them directly.

3.2.0-11 becomes 4 ints, 3, 2, 0 and 11 whereas 3.2.0-1 becomes 3, 2, 0 and 1.

Assuming you made them into arrays you compare src[3] < dest[3], src[2] < dest[2], ... inside your comparator and you are done.

This can be done easily in your case with String.split(".-") then calling Integer.getInteger(src[n]) on each entry in the resulting array.

Advanced:

Now, if you want the "Advanced" version of this I can show you a little trick.  If you take your values and combine them into a single long--something like this:

```
long l=src[3] << (16 * 3) + src[2] << (16 * 2) + src[1] << (16 * 1) + src[0];
```

This will combine all the individual fields into a single long that can be compared. 
(it will need a little casting AND the first field cannot go over version # 32767, all the others can go to 65535)

If you are sure none of the numbers will go over 255 then you could even shift by multiples of 8 instead of 16 and pack them into an int (or a long that can handle a version number with up to 7 fields--or 8 as long as the first one doesn't go over 127)

The nice part of this technique is that you take it from 4 compares down to 1 and you are only carrying around a single value.

Expert:

The "Expert" version, by the way, is to wrap all this inside a class so that you really don't care how it's implemented.  Something with an interface like this:

```
class VersionNo implements Comparable {
    public VersionNo(String version, File originalFileObject);
    public int compareTo(VersionNo target);
    public String toString();
    public File getOriginalFileObject();
}
```

Now you can change your implementation any time you want and not effect anything else in your program--you don't even "Need" to consider a separate comparator, these should automatically sort themselves when inserted in any self-respecting ordered data structure.